# most general unifier: can a variable be substituted to a variable and a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, unification

i was wondering: when doing most general unifiers(MGU), can a variable be substituted to a variable and to a function?

examples that illustrates my question:

1)loves(girlfriend(x),x) , loves(y,y)

2)loves(girlfriend(x),x) , loves(girfriend(y), Suzzie)

?

can it be done or are they wrong both?

would appreciate your explanations regarding this tricky thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question in your first paragraph, but assuming that you attempt to find an mgu for each of the sets 1) and 2):

Presupposing a stepwise algorithmic proedure where you work your way from left to right substituting differing terms until you arrive at an mgu that makes the two formulas identical:

---

1) is not unifiable at all.

A possible first substitution which identifies the terms $\text{girlfriend}(x)$ and $y$ is

$\sigma_1 = [y/\text{girlfriend}(x)]$

which gives you

$\{\text{love}(\text{girlfriend}(x),x), \text{love}(\text{girlfriend}(x),\text{girlfriend}(x))\}$.

At this point you see that the set is not unifiable: The next substitution step would be to identify $x$ and $\text{girlfriend}(x)$. The only variable available to undergo this substitution step is $x$, but $x$ occurs in the only other term avialable, which is $\text{girlfriend}(x)$, so any sustitution would just lead to an infinite recursion $\text{girlfriend}(\text{girlfriend}(...(x)))$, and hence there is no mgu.

---

2) is unifiable:

A first substitution that identifies the terms $\text{girlfriend}(x)$ and $\text{girlfriend}(y)$

is

$\sigma_1 = [x/y]$

which gives you

$\{\text{love}(\text{girlfriend}(y),y), \text{love}(\text{girlfriend}(y), \text{Suzzie})\}$

The second substitution which identifies $y$ and $\text{Suzzie}$ is

$\sigma_2 = [y/\text{Suzzie}]$

which yields the unified set

$\{\text{love}(\text{girlfriend(Suzzie)},\text{Suzzie}), \text{girlfriend(Suzzie)},\text{Suzzie})\} = \{\text{love}(\text{girlfriend(Suzzie)},\text{Suzzie})\} $

so your mgu is

$mgu = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 = [x/y][y/\text{Suzzie}] = [x/\text{Suzzie},y/\text{Suzzie}]$.

Comment: I think the OP has _two separate_ unification problems. The first is to unify `loves(girlfriend(x),x)` with `loves(y,y)`, which is impossible as you argue. The second is to unify `loves(girlfriend(x),x)` with `loves(girlfriend(y),Suzzie)` -- which is possible with the most general unifier mapping both of `x` and `y` to `Suzzie`.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Oh, that makes sense. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Also, I think your (1) is too strongly worded. For example, to unify `f(x,y)` with `f(g(y),42)` you need to substitute `x` with `g(42)`, which doesn't occur as a subterm of the input.

Comment: Re. your second comment: I was implicitly assuming a stepwise algorithmic procedure where the restriction does hold and you would first do the substitution $[x/g(y)]$ then $[y/42]$, which yields the desired unification, but that was talking about these premature substitutions while the question was about the final mgu, so I'll have to reword that as well. Thanks for pointing it out.